# C# List of Integer Arrays does not Contain Item

Tags: c#, arrays, list, arraylist, integer

My goal is to add an unknown number of integer coordinates to a collection. While I can add these coordinates to this list `List<int[]> coordList = new List<int[]>();` I cannot check if `coordList.Contains(specifiedCoordinate)`.

This is what I have so far:

```cs
List<int[]> coordList = new List<int[]>();
coordList.Add(new int[] {1, 3});
coordList.Add(new int[] {3, 6});
bool contains = coordList.Contains(new int[]{1, 3})
Console.WriteLine(contains);
```

However, `contains` is always `false` even though I specify the same values that I add.
I have tried `ArrayList` as a possible alternative, but the results are the same as using `List`.

If there's something I'm not understanding or if there's an alternative, I'm all ears.

Comment: Int arrays are objects, you created two separate objects even though the values are the same, that means they are not equal.

Comment: @RonBeyer, ah! Righto, thanks for that!

Comment: You should put your answer as an actual answer, not part of the question. You are welcome to answer your own question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems like you want:

```
bool contains = coordList.Any(a => a.SequenceEqual(new int[]{1, 3}));
```

[SequenceEqual docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.sequenceequal?view=net-6.0).

`.Any` and `.SequenceEqual` are extension methods provided by the `System.Linq` namespace. You may need to ensure that you have `using System.Linq;` at the top of your code file to make this work.

Comment: Thank you!
I'll have to get more acquainted with Linq, seems pretty useful for stuff like this.

Answer (score 1):

If you'd use value tuples, you'd get the value-comparison for free, also the code gets neater:

```
        var coordList = new List<(int x, int y)> {
                (1, 3),
                (3, 6)
        };
        //contains is now true because 
        //value tuples do value comparison in their 'Equals' override 
        bool contains = coordList.Contains((1, 3));
        Console.WriteLine(contains);
```

Answer (score 0):

*From OP*

#### Answer

So, I created a new function based on Llama's suggestion:

```cs
static bool ContainsCoordinate(int[] coords, List<int[]> coordList) {
    bool contains = coordList.Any(a => a.SequenceEqual(coords));
    return contains;
}
```

Which just works a charm.

I would also like to thank Ron Beyer for helping me understand more about object declaration and instancing,